# How to make program continue code without printing it more then once

Tags: java, if-statement

I have this code:

```
public void checkUserLuckyNumber(PC p, User u) {
    int userLuckyNumber = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Input lucky number from 1 - 10:"));
    if (userLuckyNumber < 1 || userLuckyNumber > 10) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Constants.INVALIDINPUTNUMBER);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        int threeLuckyNumbers = (int) (Math.random() * 10);

        if (userLuckyNumber == threeLuckyNumbers) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you hit a happy number");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you did not hit a lucky number");
        }
    }
}
}
```

My problem is that my program print me three time message, if user hit lucky number program print me one message "you hit a happy number" and if user miss lucky number, program print me one message "you hit a happy number" and then twice " you did not hit a lucky number".

So my question is how to make program that print just one message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`break` the loop as soon as luck number is hit!

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
     int threeLuckyNumbers = (int)(Math.random() * 10);

     if (userLuckyNumber == threeLuckyNumbers) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you hit a happy number");
     } else {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you did not hit a lucky number");
     }

      break;
    }
```

Break once as soon as you determine the hit or miss.
But then you should not be looping 3 times at first place.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please accept if found useful. @FootballHighlight-Goals-News

Comment: Oh okey, i thought that i can just one answer accept. But can you help me with one more thing?

Comment: you can raise a question , glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `break` in your `for` loop, for the success case:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    int threeLuckyNumbers = (int) (Math.random() * 10);

    if (userLuckyNumber == threeLuckyNumbers) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you hit a happy number");
        break; // I added this
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you did not hit a lucky number");
        break;
    }
}
```

The `break` keyword is used for control flow in Java code.  In the above case, when used inside the `for` loop it terminates that loop, and the code continues with whatever follows immediately after the end of the loop.

Comment: Program again print me 3 times message that i did not hit a lucky number.

Comment: Then maybe you want to break in both cases?

Comment: Thank you so much man. I have whole other idea, with `do {` and `continue`. Thank you again. Can you explain me just how break work in this situation?

Comment: Can you help me with one more thing?

Comment: No, I can't, and you should open a new question.